# PHP: Convert line break into list item and wrap part of string with span

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm converting HTML template into WordPress theme. On backend I have a custom field that outputs raw text.

This is what I want to achieve in the end:

[image: list items]

This is the HTML output I want to achieve:

```html
<li>Bor ekan <span class="disk-year">/ 2002</span></li>
<li>Baxt bo'ladi <span class="disk-year">/ 2004</span></li>
<li>Baxtliman <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
<li>Bu mening tanlovim <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
<li>Radio tinglamayman <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
<li>Yana albomlar <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
<li>Yana bitta uzun <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
<li>Yangi yil albomi <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
<li>Eng yaxshi <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
<li>Ba'zi  qo'shiqlar <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
<li>Ko'p yuklab olingan <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
<li>Yevropa hitlari <span class="disk-year">/ 2005</span></li>
```

I want user to enter strings separated with line breaks like these:

```
Music album name * / 2007*
Music album name * / 2007*
Music album name * / 2007*
Music album name * / 2007*
Music album name * / 2007*
```

1. Each string on new line should be wrapped with li tags;
2. Everything between *'s should be wrapped with span tags.

Comment: Does the `*` character exist in your string or it is for understanding?

Comment: @Mohammad       The `*` probably does  not exist yet **but should as a requirement**. Users are expected to format their input Data thus: `Music album name * / 2007*` with each  new Entry on  a New Line.....

Comment: *'s already exist in the text. User inputs text as 'Music album name * / 2007*' and '*'s later replaced by span tags.

Comment: Use `preg_replace("/([^\*]+)\*([^\*]+)\*/", "<li>$1<span>$2</span></li>", $str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could You have meant something  like below? [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/668661).

```
<?php

    $data   = "Bor ekan * / 2002*\nBaxt bo'ladi * / 2004*\nBaxtliman * / 2005*\nBu mening tanlovim * / 2005*\nRadio tinglamayman * / 2005*\nYana albomlar * / 2005*\nYana bitta uzun * / 2005*\nYangi yil albomi * / 2005*\nEng yaxshi * / 2005*\nBa'zi  qo'shiqlar * / 2005*\nKo'p yuklab olingan * / 2005*\nYevropa hitlari * / 2005*\n";

    function transformData($data){
        $output         = '';
        if(is_string($data)){
            $data       = explode('\n', $data);
        }

        foreach($data as $val){
            $extract    = preg_replace("#(.*?)\*(.*?)\*#", "<li>$1<span class='disk-year'>$2</span></li>", $val);
            $output    .= $extract . PHP_EOL;
        }

        return $output;
    }

    var_dump(transformData($data));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: preg_replace works on an array as well. I submitted another answer just using the preg_replace without a need of a for loop. The answer is inspired by Poiz answer

Answer (score 2):

Another attempt to terse the code. Inspired by Poiz answer. [Quick Test Here](https://eval.in/668929). Since preg_replace works on an array, there is no need for the for loop.

```
 $data = "Bor ekan * / 2002*\nBaxt bo'ladi * / 2004*\nBaxtliman * / 2005*\nBu mening tanlovim * / 2005*\nRadio tinglamayman * / 2005*\nYana albomlar * / 2005*\nYana bitta uzun * / 2005*\nYangi yil albomi * / 2005*\nEng yaxshi * / 2005*\nBa'zi  qo'shiqlar * / 2005*\nKo'p yuklab olingan * / 2005*\nYevropa hitlari * / 2005*\n";
 $data = explode('\n', $data);
 $data = preg_replace("#(.*?)\*(.*?)\*#", "<li>$1<span class='disk-year'>$2</span></li>", $data);
 print implode('\n', $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified @Poiz's awesome function to make it more convenient for use. I'm just posting if anybody would need it.

```
$data = "Music album name / 2007\nMusic album name / 2008\nMusic album name / 2009";
              function transformData($data){
                $output = '';
                if(is_string($data)){
                  $data = explode('\n', $data);
                }
                foreach($data as $val){
                  $extract    = preg_replace('#(.*?)\/(.*)#', "<li>$1<span class='disk-year'> / $2</span></li>", strip_tags($val));
                  $output    .= $extract . PHP_EOL;
                }
                return $output;
              }
              echo transformData($data);
```

With the above function user can enter lines just like these:

Music album name / 2007
Music album name / 2008
Music album name / 2009

And the function will display the result I showed in my question.